# trying to create a column but it also creates a default constraint with useless name

Tags: sql-server

I am using the `alter command` to add a column with not null and default value to the sql,

but when i run it it also creates the constraint with some silly words, how can i use the alter `command` to add the column also and also add the constraint with it with the name i specify

my alter is like this

```
ALTER TABLE users
    ADD role bit not null default 0;
```

Should the combined constraint with same alter command will work, not sure how to add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the constraint name within the statement as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD role bit NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Users__Role DEFAULT (0);
```

There are examples in the docs online, albeit a long way down the page: [B. Adding a column with a constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-adding-a-column-with-a-constraint)